# Why Does my Service Account Attempt to Connect to Google API via OAuth2 Return an 'invalid_grant' error?

Tags: vb.net, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I am attempting to use a Service Account to talk to the [Admin SDK Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) via the .Net Client Library.  However, the response I keep getting is a `400 Bad Request` with a json response content of `"error":"invalid_grant"`.

**Here is my code**

```
Public Sub New()

    Dim _certificate = New X509Certificate2("c:\path\to\file.psk", "notasecret" _ 
    , X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable)

    Dim _serviceAccountEmail = "email@developer.gserviceaccount.com"

    Dim _scopes As IList(Of String) = New List(Of String)()

    _scopes.Add(directory_v1.DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryUserReadonly)

    Dim credential = New ServiceAccountCredential(New 
        ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(_serviceAccountEmail) With {
            .Scopes = _scopes}.FromCertificate(_certificate))

    Dim service = New directory_v1.DirectoryService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With { _
                                                .HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                                                .ApplicationName = "AeriesConnect"})

    Dim request = service.Users.List()
    request.Domain = "my.domain.com"

    Dim users As directory_v1.Data.Users = request.Execute()

    For Each user In users.UsersValue
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("userName ID: " & user.Id)
    Next

End Sub
```

**Service Object**

My service object has the following properties.  All other properties are empty collections of the `UsersResource` or `GroupsResource`

```
service.BaseUri = 'https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1"
```

**service.HttpClientInitializer Properties**

Notice that the Token property is empty. Does that matter?  It seems like it does.  Is that my fault?

[image: service.HttpClientInitializer Properties]

**Request Object**

[image]

I get the error right at the Execute and the exception is from Google and is a `Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponseException`.

I think I've granted all the permissions I need to *BUT* keep in mind, this is for a Google Apps for Education account.

1. Logging in as a Super User to the Developer Console, I've created a project and enabled the Admin SDK API.  I've also created the Credentials.
2. As a 'Super User' in that GAFE, I've gone to the "Security --> Advanced Settings --> Manage API Client Access" area and [added my Client ID](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account) (not email) and the scope as `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user`

**Request Header**

My request header that is `POST` to `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token` has this

```
assertion=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzY29wZSI6Imh0dHBzOi8vd3d3L
mdvb2dsZWFwaXMuY29tL2F1dGgvYWRtaW4uZGlyZWN0b3J5LnVzZXIiLCJpc3MiOiI2OTY3MTQyNzg2OS1hb
XFmMjVzY204Y2N1azhycHJrMDQ2djAzb2cybGducEBkZXZlbG9wZXIuZ3NlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50LmNvbSAiLC
JhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL2FjY291bnRzLmdvb2dsZS5jb20vby9vYXV0aDIvdG9rZW4iLCJleHAiOjE0MTQ2MTY
3NDMsImlhdCI6MTQxNDYxMzE0M30.T9H-3tgOQSNdSj3MrUjJNNR5YqsxuJ97bCMJrrEJQ1Noewyv2mj
Dp96AZSZmzSxseAWrgptUv7sR4Mi21CWNACmjQjWPw8BI48sAyIclUPq6UhtMhRZDB1xX7t-Tq8NSbddJt
yJWxTc-IEAT7ixVpjjrosdG8Zcs0MgTuUgKHb8
&grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer
```

...and the last bits of it feel wrong.  Why does it feel like it suddenly has been HTML encoded?

**Question**

What have I done wrong?  I'm assuming it think's I'm not authenticated.  But what do I need to do differently?  I've used [their](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/get_started) [examples](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/get_started) to help, but I can't quite figure it out.

Comment: What does your request look like after request.Domain?

Comment: And your service after you declared that object?

Comment: invalid_grant normally means Your server’s clock is not in sync with NTP. (Solution: check the server time if its incorrect fix it. )   The service account needs to be granted access to the account you want to access using the email address like any other user.

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR I've added both the `request` and `service` object properties.

Comment: @DalmTo I've looked, and while my computer is slow by 30 seconds compared to NTP, do you think that is enough to cause this?  I'm on a computer attached to a domain, so it is not under my control.

Comment: I am now able to connect.  It appears my problem was that I had the wrong value in the Service Account Email field.  Glad I figured it out.  Feeling like an idiot for not triple checking that value.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I had the wrong value in the Service Account Email field.  Simple solution.  Took me two days to figure it out.  Ugh!